Sorting anytype argument type
I've been trying to create a system where i can store different types of data as "bundles". I should be able to get only parts of the data back.
I basically want it to work like this
test "test" {
    const allocator = testing.allocator;

    const Struct1 = struct { x: u32, y: u32 };
    const Struct2 = struct { x: u16 };
    const Struct3 = struct { x: u64 };

    const BundleTypes1 = .{ Struct1, Struct3, Struct2 };

    var bundles = try Bundles.init(BundleTypes1, allocator);
    defer bundles.deinit();

    bundles.add(.{ Struct3{ .x = 64 }, Struct1{ .x = 32, .y = 32 }, Struct2{ .x = 16 }});

    const id: usize = 0;
    _ = bundles.get(.{ Struct1 Struct3 }, id);
}

When i create bundles i generate some metadata with the offset to each type which is accessed with the typename.
I've got it working by doing this:
pub fn get(self: *Bundles, bundle_types: anytype, id: usize) CreateReturnType(bundle_types) {
    comptime assert(isStructOfPureStructTypes(bundle_types));
    const info = @typeInfo(bundle_types);
    const ReturnType = CreateReturnType(bundle_types);

    const start_offset = self.bundle_map.get(id).?;
    var rv: ReturnType = undefined;
    inline for (info.Struct.fields, std.meta.fields(ReturnType)) |bt, meta_field| {
        const m = self.meta.components[self.meta_map.get(@typeName(bt.type)).?];
        const data: *meta_field.type = @alignCast(@ptrCast(self.memory[start_offset + m.offset .. jkjkstart_offset + m.offset + m.size]));
        @field(rv, meta_field.name) = data.*;
    }
    return rv;
}


Now to the problem, the user is able to ask for the types stored in any order but the layout in memory might be something totally different. The types might be stored in the order T1 T3 T2 but the user might ask for the types in order T2 T1 T3. Right now i have to access the memory in the order the user ask for them which means i might have to jump back and forth in memory instead of getting them one after another. I don't really know how to fix this since the metadata is runtime.
How do i fix this? Thanks in advance for any help you can provide.

Without making metadata comptime, you should be able to turn the types passed into .get() into a runtime array of metadata, then find which slices of the bundle to return, then inline for to cast those back into the comptime types. There's a lot of code in this question and I'm not really sure what you're trying to do.

@pfg Ah, i understand your confusion. The thing is that the data is sorted and their offset and location in memory depends on their alignment and such so the bundle is packed more optimally in regards to cache lines.  This means that i would need all types to re-generate the metadata to get the correct offset.

@pfg i updated the question, ill think it might be more clear and easier to fix now.

maybe you could return pointers to the entries in the bundle? or make the bundle comptime based on the types it holds? jumping back and forth in memory shouldn't really be a problem, the data around the address you read is cached and then subsequent accesses (ahead or behind that one) are basically free as long as they're near the original access

@pfg ah, ofcource if i return pointers i actually never access the memory right?

correct. if you return pointers you never access the memory.

Are you maybe looking for a packed or extern struct?  Both of those have well-defined order.  Either T = packed struct { ... } or @Type(.{@"struct" = .{.layout = .extern, ...}})
